# Downcast to "foreign" class without data members

Tags: c++, downcast

Consider the following code:

```
struct A { int m; };
struct B : A { void proc () { /* ... */ };
struct C : A { void proc () { /* ... */ };

A a;
B * b = (B *) &a;
C * c = (C *) &a;
b->proc ();
c->proc ();
```

Is that legal and well-defined?

Pro: `A` is standard layout and `B` and `C` do not contain any data members.

Contra: `a` is neither of `B` nor of `C` type.

Comment: Probably unnecessary. If `B` and `C` have no state, then you should get the same behaviour from `B().proc();`.

Answer (score 1):

Formal: not valid, not well-defined. In-practice: not smart to do.

Comment: The original question, reworded:  "If I kick this hornet's nest that I didn't see any hornets around, will I get stung?"  :-)